# IDLE for Python 3.6 can't open .py files on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, idle

I just did a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04.

I downloaded pip3, python 3.6.7, discord.py, and IDLE for python 3.6.

When I go to open up .py files I have on my other computer, I don't have to option to open them with IDLE:

[image: proof that it is installed but not showing up]

The application list on the right doesn't have IDLE as an option, the thing on the left is a running IDLE shell but with no code to use as it source, and the thing on top is the software manager saying that it is installed.

Comment: How did you installed IDLE? Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep idle`. Which filemanager do you use?

Comment: I encountered the same issue. I had filed a bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.6/+bug/1840398). Appreciate you can click on "This bug affects you" in that bug report and added you comments there too so that the developers can take action. Thanks.